# Using mock library to patch a class method

Tags: python, mocking

I'm writing unit tests, and I need to mock a method call so that in most of the cases it behaved as method itself except when argument gets a special value 'insert into'. Here is a simplified production code:

```
class CommandServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rowcount = None
    def runSQL(self, sql):
        print "Do something useful"
        self.rowcount=5
        return self

class Process(object):
    def process(self):
        cs = CommandServer()
        cs.runSQL("create table tbl1(X VARCHAR2(10))")
        r = cs.runSQL("insert into tbl1 select * from tbl2")
        print "Number of rows: %s" % r.rowcount

p = Process()
p.process()
```

which prints

```
Do something useful
Do something useful
Number of rows: 5
```

I can make a mock version myself using the following code:

```
runSQL = CommandServer.runSQL
def runSQLPatch(self, sql):
    if sql.lstrip().startswith('insert into'):
        print "Patched version in use"
        class res(object):
            rowcount = -1
        return res
    else:
        return runSQL(self, sql)
CommandServer.runSQL = runSQLPatch

p = Process()
p.process()
```

which prints

```
Do something useful
Patched version in use
Number of rows: -1
```

I want to use `mock` [library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to accomplish the same (I believe that this is the library included in [python 3](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock-examples.html)). How can I do that? (Python 2.6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be entirely clear, it's only included in python 3.3 (which I'm so happy to have learned, thank you!).

Otherwise, the pattern you could use is

```
from mock import patch

with patch.object(CommandServer, 'runSQL') as runSQL:
    class res(object):
       rowcount = -1

    runSQL.return_value = res

    p = Process()
    p.process()

    for c in runSQL.call_list:
        assert c[1].lstrip().startswith('insert into') is True
```

But this would cover all cases, not just cases where you are sending `'insert into'`. This might give you a hint as to where to look, but otherwise, I don't think what you're looking for is exactly possible with mock.